# python sorting dictionary by inner list of lists

Tags: python, sorting

I am using Python 2.5. I have a dictionary with a list of lists as values

```
{'a': [['6', 3]], 'b': [['5', 1], ['6', 5]], 'c': [['446', 2],['6', 11],['67', 86]] }
```

I want to sort it by the 2nd element of the first list item, so, the above would be sorted like this:

```
'b': [['5', 1], ['6', 5]], 
'c': [['446', 2],['6', 11],['67', 86]]
'a': [['6', 3]]
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dictionary itself is unordered, so you can't sort it per se.  If you want to create a sorted list of the key-value pairs, you can do that:

```
sorted(myDict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1][0][1])
```

`iteritems` returns an iterable of (key, value) pairs, so `x[1][0][1]` there means "take the second element of this pair (which is the value), and take the first element of that (which is the first list in the list of lists) and take the second element in that --- in order words, the second element in the first list, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks.  Works great.  And, I finally went to ready up on lambda functions.

Comment: `iteritems` doesn't return a list of (key, value) pairs; it iterates a lazy sequence of such pairs. If you actually want a list, you have to use `items` (or call `list(myDict.iteritems())`.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries have no order.

However, there is a class in the standard library called `collections.OrderedDict` that retains the order of insertion. And you can create one like this:

```
>>> collections.OrderedDict(sorted(myDict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1][0][1])
OrderedDict([('b', [['5', 1], ['6', 5]]), ('c', [['446', 2], ['6', 11], ['67', 86]]), ('a', [['5', 4]])])
```

`myDict.iteritems()` returns a sequence of `(key, value)` `tuple`s. (You can also use `items`, which will return the sequence as a list instead of an iterator—but it will work in Python 3, which `iteritems` will not.)

`sorted` sorts them by the `key`.

The `key` is a function that takes the `value` from one of these `tuple`s, the 2nd element of that `value`, and the 1st element of that 2nd element, which is what you wanted to sort by.

The `OrderedDict` class does not exist in Python 2.5, but it's implemented in pure Python. If you look at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) for 2.7, there's a link to [the code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py), which you can copy and paste into your 2.5 program. Or you can use the ActiveState recipe that was borrowed into the standard library, or look for a module at PyPI that does it for you.